# RESTEasy - custom ExceptionMapper with error attributes?

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

How can I get infos about the error message without "regexing" it?

For example, the following message: "Unable to extract parameter from http request: %s value is '%s'"

I need to keep the request parameter that is in error, but I don't need to show the value.

I tried to implement the "ExceptionMapper" but I cannot get access to the relevant information about what parameter is incorrect.
I can only get the string message, and parsing it to extract the parameter feels like it could break anytime in future release if the original text changes.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What container are you running in and what version of RESTEasy are you using?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 11 and RESTEasy 6.2.1

Comment: Try turning on debug logging for debug logging for logger `org.jboss.logging`. That should log the provider that jboss-logging is using. This looks like an issue with the logging.